# Blazor component does not render sequential

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a list of Element that is rendered from razor Component but it does not render correctly. Here is my razor

```
@foreach (UIField field in component.UIFieldCollection)
{
    columnCounter++;

    @if (columnCounter == 1)
    {
        <UITextToHtml htmlString="@rowOpener" />

        <span>a @columnCounter</span>
    }
         
    @if (columnCounter > 1 && columnCounter % 3 == 1)
    { 
        <UITextToHtml htmlString="@rowCloser" />
        <UITextToHtml htmlString="@rowOpener" />

        <span>a @columnCounter</span> 
    }

    <label>@field.Caption</label>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@field.RawValue" />
}

<UITextToHtml htmlString="@rowOpener" />
```

and

```
private string rowOpener = "<div class='row'>";
private string rowCloser = "</div>";
```

The problem is, the `</div>` is rendered right away instead of waiting for `<label> <InputText>`.

could everyone give me some advise ?

below is the output html [image]

The expected result [Code Added from comment]:

```cs
<div class='row' >
   <label>Order ID </label> 
<input class='form-control' />  
<label>Order Type 
</label> 
<input class='form-control' />  
<label>Order Date </label> 
<input class='form-control' />  
</div> 
<div class='row' >   
<label>Order Status </label> 
<input class='form-control' />  
</div>
```

Comment: This is only part of your code.  Where and how are you running the code you have shown.? 
 You've missed the most important information - context.  My guess is that `component.UIFieldCollection` is empty when it's rendered, but that is a total guess!  Without context, I can't tell you why.

Comment: You can't render an incomplete div like that,  it will be auto closed as you've seen. Why are you overcomplicating this? There are plenty of examples of how to render tables/ grids out there

Comment: You are thinking too literally about markup.  Blazor uses Components, and you should not be trying to force-build your page in this way using string literals-- presumably a technique you've used with some other framework.  If you want something in a `div`, make a `.razor` component that takes RenderFragments. . . and make THOSE components (or html markup) too.

Comment: Note: I was going to clean up your code, but actually I can't understand what you are trying to do.  Are you just trying to display an array in 3 columns?

Comment: hi everyone,
i'm glad to see you start putting comment on my question.
let me explain a little bit. my idea is, I would like to put Each 3 elements in 1 `<div class='row'>`.  As  @MisterMagoo said, the `</div> auto closes right away.

The expected result is 
```<div class='row' > 
 <label>Order ID </label> <input class='form-control' />
 <label>Order Type </label> <input class='form-control' />
 <label>Order Date </label> <input class='form-control' />
 </div>
<div class='row' > 
 <label>Order Status </label> <input class='form-control' />
 </div>
```

Comment: @Bennyboy1973.  I started and then realised I did not have enough context information.  I suspect the OP is trying to build some sort of generic form builder [though I may be wrong].

Comment: @THomasLee I'm still unclear.  It's very easy to display a class instance with 3 items in it, but you have so much extra stuff-- UIFieldCollection.  What's in this collection?  Is it custom HTML created in some kind of designer that you need to reuse?

Comment: hi @Bennyboy1973, 
UIFieldCollection is list of UIField :) and on the page, I create the list of UIField to generate the HTML markup by another blazor component called UIHTMLControlComponent. my above question is, I would like set the number of UIField on 1 row. in this sample, it's 3 Fields / row.

Comment: @ThomasLee My problem is that I'm having trouble imagining any case in which creating html tags with literal strings would be better than nesting Blazor Components.  I'm suspicious that helping you do what you're trying to achieve will doom you in the long run.  I used to do this kind of thing back in PHP days, and it's not a good look for Blazor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to put Each 3 elements in 1 `<div class='row'>`.

OK, that requires a Linq solution, not a Blazor one.

```
@foreach (var chunk in component.UIFieldCollection.Chunk(3))
{
  <div>
    foreach (UIField field in chunk)
    {
      <span> @field </span>
    }
  </div>
}
```